# How to filter QnAMaker Question based on Source

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am using QnAMaker REST API in my Bot Framework to query a knowledge base.

It works fine but I would like to filter the 'questions' based on the 'source' as specified on the `requestData`. Referring to the documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage I did not see any option to do that. The documentation states that 'source' is only part of the response answer and not the request.

I tried passing 'source' as metadata to `strictFilters`.

```
Dictionary<string, object> requestData = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["question"] = question,
    ["top"] = top,
    ["strictFilters"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["source"] = "test.tsv"
    }
};

string requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
kbId = _configuration[qnaKbName];
method = "/knowledgebases/" + kbId + "/generateAnswer/";
var uri = host + method;
var response = await Post(uri, requestBody);
return response;
```

Request JSON format-

```
{"question":"flexible working","top":5,"strictFilters":{"source":"test.tsv"}}
```

It does not work and I get below response-

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Parameter is null"
  }
}
```

Tried creating the Request JSON like this-

```
{"question":"sabbatical","top":5,"strictFilters":[{"name":"source","value":"test.tsv"}]}
```

Got below response-

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unspecified",
    "message": "Something happened. Please retry after some time."
  }
}
```

Is there any option to do that? Please let me know if I can provide more details..

Comment: Can't you simply filter the results you got, as they contain the `source` field? Because you try to use a filter but these filter values must be specified in the metadata, currently it is not done

Comment: @NicolasR Here- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14778 they say we can. Also filtering the result is cumbersome and performance costly if we get a big response to filter through.

Comment: As they said in the post in Github you are mentioning, `source` is not an information in the metadata: "Source is not a metadata. We consider metadata that are explicitly added as metadata as a name:value pair."

Comment: @NicolasR Yes, I am in touch with them.

Comment: So if you want to use these filters, ensure first that you add the metadata. then it should work

Comment: @NicolasR So how do I do that?

Comment: There is no easy way if you are providing files or url, you will have to add these items "by hand". An option would be: create your KB with files / urls. Then download your KB to get the extracted items, and create a new KB with those items (or use PUT method to replace KB items), adding on the way the metadata property with the right value. All available methods are listed here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff

Comment: I think I got the issue. I need to add the filters in the QnAMaker KB in name/value format. I will try it and see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: That's it, by default metadata is empty, and when you create your items of your KB by providing url/files you cannot specify a global value for each item found in these url/files

Answer (score 0):

the error `BadArgument, Parameter is null` comes when input json being passed does not match with QnA API request body. For example if API is expecting `{"question":"this is my question"}` and we pass `{"questionAB":"this is my question"}`, this will throw error.